# service worker cache vs memory cache

Tags: javascript, performance, caching, service-worker, browser-cache

I found suggested in many places online that caching client application **asset** files with service worker will improve **app load time**. But found that the (memory cache and disc cache) is loading the files faster than the service worker. Is there any advantage in using a service worker to cache asset files?.

I am aware that the service worker is used to support the offline application and give better cache control.

But will it have any load time improvements if the application is online?
or if it is for load time improvement, we should avoid using **service worker**?